# Website access log in Linux/CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, ip, log-files

I cant locate the file containing a log of all the IP addresses from where people have accessed my website. I'm running Redhat / CentOS linux system

Comment: try the command: last. It processes a binary log file at: /var/log/last.log.

Comment: Sorry - I wanted to get a list of IP addresses where users have accessed my website from... @n8whnp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand what the fuss was all about. I was looking for this and I found it:

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
```

Answer (score 1):

> accessed my website

It would have been helpful if you'd said that in the first place.

It would also be helpful if you'd mentioned what webserver you are using.

Assuming you are running a standard version of Apache without unusual log configs, then the information you need should be in the access_log files which should be in /var/log/httpd